# Django: unable to get repr for class 'django.db.models.query.datetimequeryset'

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-1.7

I am trying to filter some data in Django like this:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(tense="future").values_list('date_updated').datetimes('date_updateded', 'hour').annotate(updated_count=Count('name'))
```

I am using Pycharm for debugging, and pycharm shows:

```
Django: unable to get repr for class 'django.db.models.query.datetimequeryset'
```

And I get this on my view (browser):

```
UnboundLocalError at /myview/
local variable 'sql' referenced before assignment
```

How can I fix this?

(I am trying to filter based on 'tense', get the time within an hour interval, and count the names; expecting an output something like this    (date, updated_count))

EDIT, added traceback:

```
Traceback:
File "/home/ahmad/redvenv/redcloud/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response 111. response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/home/ahmad/redvenv/redcloud/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view 21.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/ahmad/redvenv/redcloud/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py" in wrapped_view 57.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/home/ahmad/redvenv/redcloud/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view 69.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/ahmad/redvenv/redcloud/lib/python3.4/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch 452.             response = self.handle_exception(exc)

File "/home/ahmad/redvenv/redcloud/lib/python3.4/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch 449.             response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/ahmad/redvenv/redcloud/lib/python3.4/site-packages/rest_framework/decorators.py" in handler 50.             return func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/home/ahmad/redvenv/redcloud/redcloud/docServer/docServer/api_views.py" in monitoring 456.     data = ChartData.get_chart_data()

File "/home/ahmad/redvenv/redcloud/redcloud/docServer/docServer/api_views.py" in get_chart_data 445.         data['onAudit'] = ObjectNode.on_session_data()

File "/home/ahmad/redvenv/redcloud/redcloud/docServer/docServer/models/graph.py" in on_session_data 176.         return Audit.chart_data_formatter(loginCount)

File "/home/ahmad/redvenv/redcloud/redcloud/docServer/docServer/models/monitoring.py" in chart_data_formatter 34.         list_of_data_items = [list(elem) for elem in chartData]

File "/home/ahmad/redvenv/redcloud/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in __iter__ 141.         self._fetch_all()

File "/home/ahmad/redvenv/redcloud/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _fetch_all 966.             self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())

File "/home/ahmad/redvenv/redcloud/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in results_iter 1130.         for rows in self.execute_sql(MULTI):

File "/home/ahmad/redvenv/redcloud/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql 775.             sql, params = self.as_sql()

File "/home/ahmad/redvenv/redcloud/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in as_sql 133.         grouping, gb_params = self.get_grouping(having_group_by, ordering_group_by)

File "/home/ahmad/redvenv/redcloud/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in get_grouping 586. if sql not in seen:

Exception Type: UnboundLocalError at /myview/
Exception Value: local variable 'sql' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: Please show the full traceback.

Comment: @Alasdair , updated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are hitting [this bug](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/24222), which was fixed in Django 1.8.

Comment: Thanks for that, but do you know any tricks to achieve my goal? (I am trying to filter based on 'tense', get the time within an hour interval, and count the names; expecting an output something like this (date, updated_count))

Comment: If you want to use `datetimes` and `annotate`, I think you'll have to upgrade. Sorry, I don't have any other suggestions.